# unity, how works the RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle() function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to follow this "tutorial":
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ui-follow-scene-objects.364143/

but the guy says that should use `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`

I tried to do:

```
Vector2 localPoint;     

RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(theRectTransformOfMyImage, transform.position, theCamera, out localPoint);
```

but the image goes to the corner screen, instead of being in the object...

any idea?

Edit:

More info, I have a 3D space, it's an enemy scene object with a following health bar image:

In the scripts, the variables are:

```
private Camera _camera;
  private RectTransform _healthBarReact;

  ...


  void Update()
  {
    // it works more or less, with the problem of "the UI element move at half the speed"
    Vector2 screenPoint = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(_camera, transform.position);
    _healthBarReact.position = screenPoint;

    // this doesn't work, the healthBar images goes to the screen corner
    Vector2 localPoint;
   RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(_healthBarReact, screenPoint, _camera, out localPoint);
    _healthBarReact.position = localPoint;
  }
```

the script is attached to the Enemy game object

Comment: You need to pass a screen position, not a world position.

Comment: what do you mean, inside the ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle func instead of using transform.position, use RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(_camera, transform.position)? thats not working... thanks!

Comment: It's hard to help with that two lines of code. You want to move the UI in world space? Fine! Where is is this script attached to? Where is the rest of the script. Describe what's happening in the current code.

Comment: updated with a bit more info, tell me if it's not enough, thanks!

Comment: You should put a complete code sample and explain clearly, do you want a health bar follow an enemy like in a SHMUPS or what ?

Comment: The example code is in the linked page,  the hp bar should follow the enemy,  like in his head, or bottom